# system folder does not exist in /usr/lib/systemd

Tags: systemd

I am new to ubuntu and using ubuntu 16.04. i want to create a unit file. I know i have to create it under /usr/lib/systemd/system , but there is no folder named system in my systemd folder. I would be very thankful to know what to do

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu has not completed the [`/usr` merge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) yet, so many configuration files, including systemd units, are actually in `/lib`, not `/usr/lib`. However, they don’t always update the manpages to account for this.

That said, if you’re writing your own unit file you should not place it in `/usr/lib` or `/lib` anyways – that directory belongs to the package manager. Your (the system administrator’s) custom configuration belongs in `/etc` (`/etc/systemd/system/`), or possibly in your home directory if it’s a user unit specific to your user.